# Is my AWK script correct?

Tags: awk

I have a file which has some columns. I have written a small `awk` thingy to aggregate columns (summing them) based on first, second and third columns of the file.

Here is an example of the data:

```
Cairo, Summer, Building#A, 34, 45, 66, 97
Cairo, Summer, Building#B, 21, 2, 2, 0.9
Cairo, Summer, Building#C, 23, 11, 2, 12
NYC, Summer, Unit#5,       22, 34, 23, 1
NYC, Winter, Apt#45,       32, 42, 33, 20
```

Here is the script I am using:

```
awk -F, '{gsub("%", ""); \
a[$1","$2","$3]+=$4;b[$1","$2","$3]+=$5;c[$1","$2","$3]+=$6;d[$1","$2","$3]+=$7}
END{for(i in a) if(a[i]+b[i]+c[i]+d[i] > 0) print i","a[i]","b[i]","c[i]","d[i]}'
input_file > output_file
```

Its giving me results.

Question is: Is this the right approach? If so, is this good enough wrt memory and speed? If none, is there someone kind enough to suggest a better alternative? :-) Thanks.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Looks like it's working fine using first three columns as dynamic variable using awk's array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write it this way

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} 
             {for(i=4;i<=NF;i++) 
                {k=$1 FS $2 FS $3; ks[k]; a[k,i]+=$i}} 
       END   {for(k in ks) 
                {printf "%s", k; 
                 for(i=4;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s", OFS a[k,i]; print ""}}' file
```

not much for efficiency but **DRY** principle, keys are defined in one place, use FS/OFS instead of hardcoded strings, use for loop and NF instead of fixing the number of fields, printf in case formatting is required etc.

Note that for the given input data there is no aggregation happening since the keys are all unique.